# Getting "office-addin-debugging is not recognized as an internal or external command" after running an Excel task pane project with yo office

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am unable to start an `office-js` Excel Task pane Add-in project due to "office-addin-debugging" apparently being missing. However, I noticed the module is included in my dev-dependencies. I followed the example tutorial on the official website. The error messages can be seen below

```
'office-addin-debugging' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! office-addin-taskpane-js@0.0.1 start:web: `office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the office-addin-taskpane-js@0.0.1 start:web script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. Running `npm install` didn't install all dependencies for some reason, but individually installing the missing scripts worked.

I ran `npm install office-addin-debugging` manually and it worked.

Comment: You may also want to consider installing the package globally, i.e `npm install -g office-addin-debugging`.  Just depends on your setup and reqs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to an installation of this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-debugging

From the documentation on the website:

> Syntax:
>
> **office addin-debugging start  [options]**
>
> manifest: path to manifest file.

It looks like you're running command

```
office-addin-debugging manifest.xml
```

but the real command is

```
office addin-debugging start manifest.xml
```

Comment: It was written as "office-addin-debugging manifest.xml" in the package.json after creating the app with the "yo office" command

Comment: @Olalekan I'd appreciate the green tick if it qualifies as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By running `npm i` it worked and installed remaining dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it was because my Excel version was 2013. It worked fine when I switched to 2016 since that's the minimum version you need to have before you can run office-js